# RadiusNetwork's Android iBeacon Library

Tags: android-studio, ibeacon-android

I'm trying to use the [Android IBeacon Library](https://github.com/RadiusNetworks/android-ibeacon-service) in my application. I have added all dependencies in my gradle file and gradle sync fails with the following error:

```
Failed to refresh Gradle project 'IBeaconTest'
        Could not find com.radiusnetworks:AndroidIBeaconLibrary:0.7.6.
        Required by:
        IBeaconTest:ibeacon:1.0
```

**This is my project's structure:**

[image]

**Update 1:**

**Module's build.gradle file(IbeaconTest/ibeacon/build.gradle):**

```
apply plugin: 'android'

android {
compileSdkVersion 19
buildToolsVersion '19.0.1'

defaultConfig {
    minSdkVersion 18
    targetSdkVersion 19
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        runProguard false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
    }
}
}

dependencies {
compile 'com.radiusnetworks:AndroidIBeaconLibrary:0.7.6@aar'
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
}
```

**Main project's build.gradle(IBeaconTest/build.gradle):**

```
buildscript {
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    flatDir {
        dirs 'libs'
    }
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.9.+'
}
}

allprojects {
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}
}
```

Comment: Please add text versions of text files, not screenshots. Also, could you please add the other build.gradle files to your question? I don't see what could be causing that error in the build file you've got.

Comment: @ScottBarta I have added the main build.gradle file

Comment: How about android-ibeacon-service-master?

Comment: @ScottBarta Sorry, Added..

Comment: Can you show the relative paths for "Main project's build.gradle" and "build.gradle file"?  I am unclear based on your description which is which.

Comment: @davidgyoung Have added the path

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try putting the `flatDir` configuration in your module's build.gradle file.

Like this:

**Module's build.gradle file(IbeaconTest/ibeacon/build.gradle):**

```
apply plugin: 'android'

android {
compileSdkVersion 19
buildToolsVersion '19.0.1'

defaultConfig {
    minSdkVersion 18
    targetSdkVersion 19
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    flatDir {
        dirs 'libs'
    }
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        runProguard false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
    }
}
}

dependencies {
  compile 'com.radiusnetworks:AndroidIBeaconLibrary:0.7+@aar'
  compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
}
```

Comment: Ok. That worked. Feel so stupid for this mistake. Thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 0):

You're going through more work than necessary to include the library.  From their quick start (http://developer.radiusnetworks.com/ibeacon/android/configure.html), you can use the library in Android Studio by doing this:

1. Download the AAR file (http://developer.radiusnetworks.com/ibeacon/android/download.html)
2. Create a /libs directory inside your module directory and copy the AAR file there.
3. Edit your build.gradle file, and add a "flatDir" entry to your repositories like so:

   ```
   repositories {
       mavenCentral()
       flatDir {
           dirs 'libs'
       }
   }
   ```
4. Edit your build.gradle file to add this AAR as a dependency like so:

   ```
   dependencies {
       compile 'com.radiusnetworks:AndroidIBeaconLibrary:0.7.1@aar'
   }
   ```

Follow these instructions instead of including it as a library project like you have.

The way you're currently doing it, when including the library as a project, that error is happening because it's expecting `sonatypeRepo` to be set to a URL for the Maven repository, but it's not defined anywhere. But if you follow their instructions for adding the library, you shouldn't have to worry about it.

Comment: I tried that and got the following error. That's why thought of importing as a library project. `Failed to refresh Gradle project 'IBeaconTest'Could not find com.radiusnetworks:AndroidIBeaconLibrary:0.7.6.
Required by:
            IBeaconTest:ibeacon:1.0`

Comment: Hmm, you should copy that AAR into the libs directory for your app module (IBeaconTest/ibeacon/libs). Did you put it there?

Comment: yeah. I have it in my application module's lib folder.